# Passar resultado do SQL para JSON

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Olá, Quero passar o resultado de um select para json, mas não consigo verificar o porque não consigo visualizar o mesmo.

Portanto alguém saberia me dizer porque este código não imprime nada?

```
include_once 'conexao.php';

$query = "SELECT client_id, name, email FROM client";
$result = $dbcon->query($query);
$rows = array();    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
        $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Resultado do `var_dump($rows)`:

```
array(8) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["client_id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["name"]=> string(26) "Fernanda Neri Duarte Silva"
        ["email"]=> string(18) "fernanda@gmail.com"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["client_id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["name"]=> string(36) "Elaine Cristina Gon�alves Durvalino "
        ["email"]=> string(16) "elaine@gmail.com"
    }
```

Comment: Isso é uma resposta de requisição ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Tente alterar o conteúdo do seu `while` para o seguinte:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
  $vclientid = $row['client_id'];
  $vname = $row['name'];
  $vemail = $row['email'];

  $rows['client'][] = array('client_id' => $vclientid, 'name' => $vname, 'email' => $vemail);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer assim:

```
$array[0] =  array('jujuba', 'bola', 'cachorro');
$array[1] =  array('carro', 'da like', 'em mim o/');

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);

var_dump(json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

Adicione o parâmetro `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`

Comparando resultados:

```
// Sem JSON_FORCE_OBJECT
string(63) "[["jujuba","bola","cachorro"],["carro","da like","em mim o\/"]]"

// com JSON_FORCE_OBJECT    
string(95) "{"0":{"0":"jujuba","1":"bola","2":"cachorro"},"1":{"0":"carro","1":"da like","2":"em mim o\/"}}"
```

Fiz uma classe (ainda to aprimorando) que faz debug se, quiser da uma olhada 
[www.bulfaitelo.com.br/2016/11/debugar-variaveis-e-classes-com-o.html](http://www.bulfaitelo.com.br/2016/11/debugar-variaveis-e-classes-com-o.html)

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta. O problema eram os acentos. Tive que codificar para UTF-8 para conseguir resolver.

A resolução foi até um pouco simples. Veja:

**

```
$query = "SELECT client_id, name, email FROM `client`";
$result = $dbcon->query($query);
$myArray = array(); 
while($fetch = $result->fetch_assoc()) {        
    $myArray[] = array("client_id" => utf8_encode($fetch['client_id']), "name" => utf8_encode($fetch['name']), "email" => utf8_encode($fetch['email']));        
}


$json = json_encode($myArray);
echo $json;**
```

Comment: Marque como resposta certa quando der.

Comment: Pode deixar! =)